# Multiple Voltage Switch Mode Power Supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Building a multiple voltage power supply for an extremely harsh environment.  Will be in a factory type environment with heavy equipment.  Looking for a sanity check on the schematic and board and any advice you may have to strengthen the device.

Schematic
[image: Power Supply Schematic]
<sub>(source: [stealthmicro.com](http://www.stealthmicro.com/files/Power-Supply-Schematic.png))</sub>

Board Layout
[image: Power Supply Board]
<sub>(source: [stealthmicro.com](http://www.stealthmicro.com/files/Power-Supply-Board.png))</sub>

Or if you would rather download the eaglecad files to look at them that way.
http://www.stealthmicro.com/files/Power-Supply.zip

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might look into using the [A4490 Triple Output Step-Down Regulator](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Part_Numbers/4490/4490.pdf), it would save quite a bit of space -- and also some money.

Comment: I do not have Eagle installed to my computer, so this question is a bit stingy on information. How many layers is this? Is the bottom layer all solid ground with no breaks? What are your design constraints in terms of size, budget and performance?

Answer (score 1):

> Building a multiple voltage power supply for an extremely harsh
>   environment. Will be in a factory type environment with heavy
>   equipment.

I smell problems if you are not isolating incoming supply from outputs. I'd use something like a [TEN 30-2412WI](http://www.tracopower.com/fileadmin/medien/dokumente/pdf/datasheets/ten30wi.pdf) from Traco: -

- Input 10V to 40V dc
- Output 12V dc at 2.5A (30 watts)
- Voltage accuracy 1%

The output is substantially isolated from the input supply thus, if you have any factory fault currents passing-by they are not going to fry your electronics. Add a 3V3 and 5V switcher on the output to get the supplies you need.